# Unable to apply changes on device: XXXXX. Error is: Socket connection timed out

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I have a problem when I want to build my Nativescript app on an Android emulator.

So the first thing I've  done is tns create my app with an --ng flag for the angular framework. After that i try to run it on an emulator and the last message I've get before the error is that it is "Succesfully installed on device with identifier 'emulator'". 
I've tried the whole https://docs.nativescript.org/releases/upgrade-instructions and got stuck at upgrading typescript and angular dependencies because it says it does not contain a package.json file.

I've run some NScore applications succesfully on the emulator but this is my first NG app and I've hit a wall. I've saw the firebase thread too about this particular theme but I don't use firebase for my app.

Comment: To debug this issue, you can build & run it in Android Studio so that you will see if it's a bug related to NS CLI or a bug in the project itself. After build the project for android platform, open it in Android studio, build & run as a normal android project then check if there is other error message.

Comment: If you have created a whole new project, why it needs an upgrade? Isn't already latest? You should find `package.json` at root of your project, do you? You are on Windows / Mac?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error trying to run nativescript on a particular device. check the storage of the device you are trying to build on.

In my own case it was storage issues that lead to that error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was a secondary space in Mi Note 7. For some reason, nativescript was installing the app in the second space (even when first space is active)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, by Updating App ID only in package.json

To resolve the issue, I manually updated the App ID in the following file.

**App_Resources\Android\settings.json**
{"appId":"org.nativescript.appid","minSdkVersion":null,"targetSdkVersion":null}